# Can no longer retrieve snapshot data from Ibrokers

Tags: r, ibrokers

This code used to work for many years but stopped working in early 2023:

```
library(IBrokers)
tws <- twsConnect()
AUDUSD <- twsCurrency("AUD","USD")
data <- reqMktData(tws,AUDUSD,snapshot=TRUE)
```

Output:

> ```
> Error in reqMktData(tws, AUDUSD, snapshot = TRUE) : 
>  Snapshot not working (?)
> ```

However, if I switch to "snapshot = FALSE" I do get never ending data.

Does anyone know how to fix the aformentioned code to work with snapshot = TRUE?

I was expecting to get a row of data with the latest snap (when `snapshot=TRUE`) but now i get an error.